# Maximum priority queue functions

Tags: java, priority-queue

I define a maximum priority queue as below:

```
    PriorityQueue<Integer> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(Collections.reverseOrder());

    queue.add(25);
    queue.add(3);
    queue.add(1);
    queue.add(3);
    queue.add(4);
```

I need to understand how this works especially when does the 1 gets the index of 2 only (not 4)?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has no guaranteed order (https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/PriorityQueue.html):

> The `Iterator` provided in method `iterator()` and the `Spliterator` provided in method `spliterator()` are not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order. If you need ordered traversal, consider using `Arrays.sort(pq.toArray())`.

Normally you retrieve elements according to their natural order using the `poll()` method, for example:

```
 while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
     var element = queue.poll();
     ...
 }
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to look at the internals of the class, [this part of the code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/PriorityQueue.java) may be relevant (it basically uses a heap data structure):

```
/**
 * Priority queue represented as a balanced binary heap: the two
 * children of queue[n] are queue[2*n+1] and queue[2*(n+1)].  The
 * priority queue is ordered by comparator, or by the elements'
 * natural ordering, if comparator is null: For each node n in the
 * heap and each descendant d of n, n <= d.  The element with the
 * lowest value is in queue[0], assuming the queue is nonempty.
 */
transient Object[] queue;
```

Answer (score 1):

This class use structure called [Heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)), and store it in array.

You will receive objects in proper order when you `poll` them.

Comment: Can you explain how they do the ordering? I am sure it's fixed as each time when I debug, I see the same order.

Comment: I suggest you to read wiki article, I don't remember all details.